# jQuery is triggering submit event when calling .submit() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a ton of questions on SO asking why jQuery method 'submit()' is NOT triggering submit event.

I am asking the exact opposite:
Why is jQuery triggering submit event when calling submit method and how to get around this?

Here a simple JSFiddle showing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/vncu675x/

```js
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("form").find(":submit").text(Math.random());
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure? " + i++)) {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it's a jQuery matter because pure JavaScript implementation is working as expected.

Comment: Seems like bad design to me. Could you maybe show us your intended use, so maybe we can recommend you another way to solve your problem. Or do you 100% NEED to use the jQuery `.submit()` in a recursive call?

Comment: Cause The submit() method triggers the submit event all the time and on submit event you call confirm() method, dont use .submit() on the method.

Comment: There's probably a dupe (at least in comments) - use: `$("form")[0].submit();`  You're calling jquery submit, which (not surprisingly) raises the event) - instead call the javascript native submit on the form

Comment: @MauriceNino, it's almost the same use, when the user submits the form, if there is any warning displayed on the page, a confirm alert will display the warning again for double validation. In don't really need that particular design, it is just what I usually did back in the days and it seems to not working anymore.

Comment: @freedomn-m your solution seems to work, if you want to post an answer I will probably mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$("form").submit();
```

is the same as `$("form").trigger("submit")` - ie it raises the submit event, which is the event that you're handling.

Instead, use the js native submit event by converting the jquery object to a DOM object:

```
$("form")[0].submit();
```

Even though they have the same name (`submit`) the two functions are for different types so have different actions.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("form").find(":submit").text(Math.random());
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure? " + i++)) {
            $("form")[0].submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```